# Remove "Change" and "Repair" buttons in Add or Remove Programs

Tags: wix

I have created a Wix installer and have packed it in a bootstrap program.

When I execute the bootstrap program it creates the following entries in the registry :

[alt text http://n2.nabble.com/file/n4011693/Up.jpg](http://n2.nabble.com/file/n4011693/Up.jpg)

When I run the bootstrap program it installs well and when I run the Add/Remove programs it shows "Change" button and "Repair" button. My requirement is that

- I want these two buttons to be one as "Change/Repair" like in other applications
- When I select this button I want my bootstrap program (setup.exe) to run and not the msi

This is my code area :

```
<Property Id="EXTUNINSTALL" Value="0"/>
<Property Id="UNINSTALLEXE" Value="msiexec.exe"/>

<!-- The Uninstall shortcut target executable & arguments-->
<CustomAction Id="SetUNINSTALLEXE_EXT" Property="UNINSTALLCMD"
                     Value="[INSTALLEREXEDIR][INSTALLEREXE]"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetUNINSTALLARG_EXT"
              Property="UNINSTALLARG"
              Value="/MAINTENANCE /SILENT="SGWLRPFCE"  
                     /LANG="[ProductLanguage]""/>
<CustomAction Id="SetSYSTEMARPCOMPONENT"
              Property="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT"
              Value="1"/>

<CustomAction Id="SetUNINSTALLARG"
              Property="UNINSTALLARG"
              Value="/x [ProductCode]"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetUNINSTALLEXE"
              Property="UNINSTALLCMD"
              Value="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"/>

<CustomAction Id="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" Property="ARPINSTALLLOCATION"
         Value="[MAININSTALLERFOLDER]" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
  <Custom Action="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" After="CostFinalize"/>
  <Custom Action="SetUNINSTALLEXE_EXT"
          After="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION"><![CDATA[EXTUNINSTALL=1]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetUNINSTALLARG_EXT"
          After="SetUNINSTALLEXE_EXT"><![CDATA[EXTUNINSTALL=1]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetSYSTEMARPCOMPONENT"
          After="SetUNINSTALLARG_EXT"><![CDATA[EXTUNINSTALL=1]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetUNINSTALLARG"
          After="SetSYSTEMARPCOMPONENT"><![CDATA[EXTUNINSTALL=0]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetUNINSTALLEXE"
          After="SetUNINSTALLARG"><![CDATA[EXTUNINSTALL=0]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 49):

You can set the [ARPNOMODIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367590%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [ARPNOREPAIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367592%28VS.85%29.aspx) properties in wix, which will disable the "change" and "repair" options for your product in the "add/remove programs" list. (This is actually equivalent to leppie's answer, but it's a better idea to use the Windows Installer properties rather than hacking at the registry directly.)

```xml
<Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" /> 
<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
```

Comment: hi wcoenen,

My requirement is not just to disable Modify and Repair in the Add/Remove programs but also to make the Remove button display as Change/Remove. When I click on this button I want my setup.exe to work.
Thanx for your response.
BR.,
tvks

Comment: This is techbically true. The properties just have to be set to something  But for some reason I'm really used to seeing 1's i nthe property table and no other text.  Probably because this is the way InstallShield authored it for so many years before using WiX.

Answer (score 8):

As per @Wim Coenen
To disable Remove “Change” and “Repair” buttons in Add or Remove Programs set following property.

**ARPNOREPAIR** and **ARPNOMODIFY**

This is sample code for disable Repair and Upgrade option.

```xml
<Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" /> 
<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion for the first part of the question:

> "I want these two buttons to be one as "Change/Repair" like in other applications"

I am running Windows 7 and the only thing close to this option is some applications having 'Uninstall/Change' merged together.

To accomplish ONE button (existing in Wix 3.7) 'Uninstall/Change' instead of 'Uninstall' and 'Change' separately the bundle tag has to be adjusted as below.

```
<Bundle ...
        DisableModify="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some registry key examples from NSIS. Should put you in the right direction.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Example2 "NoModify" 1
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Example2 "NoRepair" 1
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanx your quick reply.

I will try this "NoModify" and "NoRepair". Meanwhile this does not finish my core requirement. When I select the Remove button then I want the boot program (setup.exe) to run in the place of msiexec. How can this be achieved ?

I am able to see the setup.exe in the folder "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Installations\{27161ACE-7BDE-44a2-862D-A8158FCB9201}" of the system where installation is done.

Regards,

tvks

Comment: Hi,

Tried inserting these two "NoModify" and "NoRepair". No use. There is no change.

:(

Regards,

tvks